# Join creates wrong result query

Tags: mysql, sql, join, sum, left-join

When I do a sum and a left join in my query, the result is no longer correct. This comes because in the one table the id on which I join is more common, how can I prevent the sum from going wrong?

I have a table called `Norm`

```
ID: 1  LocationID: 1   Norm: 0,22

ID: 1  LocationID: 1   Norm: 0,25
```

And I have a table called `Hour`

```
ID: 1   LocationID: 1

ID: 2   LocationID: 1

ID: 3   LocationID: 1
```

Query:

```
SELECT N.LocationID, SUM(N.Norm) FROM Norm N
```

Result:

```
LocationID: 1   Sum(N.Norm): 0,47
```

Query:

```
SELECT N.LocationID, SUM(N.Norm) FROM Norm N LEFT JOIN Hour H ON 
N.LocationID = H.LocationID
```

Result:

```
LocationID: 1 Sum(N.Norm): 1,41
```

Script:

```
CREATE TABLE Norm` ( `ID` INT NOT NULL , `LocationID` INTNOT NULL , 
`Norm` DECIMAL(10,2) NOTNULL );

INSERT INTO `Norm`(`ID`, `LocationID`, `Norm`) 
VALUES (1,1, 0.22);

INSERT INTO `Norm`(`ID`, `LocationID`, `Norm`) 
VALUES (2,1, 0.25)


CREATE TABLE `Hour` ( `ID` INT NOT NULL , `LocationID` INTNOT NULL );

INSERT INTO `Hour`(`ID`, `LocationID`) VALUES (1, 1);
INSERT INTO `Hour`(`ID`, `LocationID`) VALUES (2, 1);
INSERT INTO `Hour`(`ID`, `LocationID`) VALUES (3, 1);
```

I need the join but want the sum to be correct as in the first how can I do this?

Comment: You need a GROUP BY!

Comment: You need to know basics about group functions and group by clause.

Comment: You can Join also on ID:    SELECT N.LocationID, SUM(N.Norm) FROM Norm N LEFT JOIN Hour H ON 
N.LocationID = H.LocationID AND N.ID = H.ID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### you can try this

```
   SELECT N.LocationID
        , SUM(N.Norm) 
     FROM Norm N 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT distinct locationid FROM Hour ) AS H 
       ON N.LocationID = H.LocationID
 GROUP BY N.LocationID
```

Answer (score 1):

this will work :

```
SELECT N.LocationID,(select sum(norm) from norm) FROM Norm N LEFT JOIN Hour H ON 
N.LocationID = H.LocationID group by N.LOCATIONID;
```